# Sequentially displaying bullet comments in a Mathematica presentation

Tags: notebooks, formatting, cells, slideshows

Playing around with the 11.3 presenter tools today. I have generated a presentation entitled "Polynomials".

10 slides with Title and 9 sections. My goal was to create a presentation with 5 slides. Title, General Information(dynamic bullets) and 3 manipulates.

I have actually acheived the look I was going for but still feel somewhat defeated. Here is the notebook in .cdf format uploaded to my Dropbox [PolynomialPresentation.cdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7m8l6jy666bhdz2/PolynomialPresentation.cdf?dl=0)

The effect of dynamically updating the bullets so my students can focus on one discussion at a time was acheived by dupilcating the general information slide and adding a new item cell for each one.

Can anyone explain how to do this in one slide or point me to a resource?

Comment: If you are going to let the students have some sort of handout it may be better to do the sequential build-up. Otherwise the final form may obliterate the starting form. I have not downloaded you presentation because the download system wants me to add other extras.

Comment: @Hugh changed the file to my Dropbox. Should always be available now without any strings attached.